# Vue-auth conditionnal redirect after login and role permissions

Tags: authentication, vue.js

I'm trying websanova/vue-auth for my app and I don't figure how to achieve these two things :

- Redirect after login depending on user's role
- Grant acces to some routes depending on user's role

## Redirect after login depending on user's role

In my Login.vue component, in `this.$auth.login()`, I tried to use `this.$auth.redirect()` as in the docs (https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth/blob/master/docs/Methods.md#redirect) but I don't understand how it works or how configure this, because `redirect.from.name` doesn't exists and `console.log(this.$auth.redirect()` return `null`

I try to set the `redirect` parameter of `this.$auth.login()` like this : `redirect: {name: this.$auth.user().role == 2 ? 'admin.dashboard' : 'dashboard'},` but it doesn't work as it always redirect to the dashboard.

In the `success()` method of `this.$auth.login()`, I can see that `this.$auth.user().role` equals `2`, but I think redirect is defined before before the user is fetched...

here's the code :

```
login(){
  var app = this
  var redirect = this.$auth.redirect()
  this.$auth.login({
    params: {
      email: app.email,
      password: app.password
    },
    success: function () {
      console.log(this.$auth.redirect()) // null
      console.log(this.$auth.user().role) // 2
    },
    error: function () {},
    rememberMe: true,
    // try 1
    //redirect: {name: redirect ? redirect.from.name : 'dashboard'},
    // try 2
    redirect: {name: this.$auth.user().role == 2 ? 'admin.dashboard' : 'dashboard'},
    fetchUser: true,
  });
}
```

## Grant acces to some routes depending on user's role

I want to grant access to the admin dashboard only for admins.
According to the doc, it can by done this way : `auth: {roles: 'admin', redirect: '/admin/login', forbiddenRedirect: '/admin/403'}`

But it does'nt work and I do'nt understand how to configure.

The fetched user has a `role` attribute, set to `2` for admin. How can I make the matching with the `roles` awaited value ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I was a little tired yesterday, I found how to solve my issues by reading the docs a little more ;)

## Redirect after login depending on user's role

Let's forget I totally misunderstood the purpose of `this.$auth.redirect()` (not for redirecting but to know if a redirection is in process :p )

So, to redirect user's depending on their role after login, I made this way :

1/ Prevent default login redirection in vue-auth with the `loginData` options

```
Vue.use(require('@websanova/vue-auth'), {
  auth: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/auth/bearer.js'),
  http: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/http/axios.1.x.js'),
  router: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/router/vue-router.2.x.js'),
  loginData: {redirect: ''}
  ...
})
```

2/ Handle redirection in my Login.vue componenent, in the `success()` callback of `$auth.login()`

```
this.$auth.login({
  params: {
    email: app.email,
    password: app.password
  },
  success: function () {
    // handle redirection
    let redirectTo
    if (redirect) {
      redirectTo = redirect.from.name
    } else {
      redirectTo = this.$auth.user().role === 2 ? 'admin.dashboard' : 'dashboard'
    }
    this.$router.push({name: redirectTo})
  },
  error: function () {},
  rememberMe: true,
  fetchUser: true,
})
```

## Grant acces to some routes depending on user's role

I was just missing an info from the [Options docs](https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth/blob/master/docs/Options.md#rolesvar-roles) : the `rolesVar` parameter that is use to tell vue-auth which user's attribute use for roles checking.

My users have the `role` attribute set to `1` for regular users and to `2` for admins.

So I add `rolesVar: 'role'` to vue-auth options :

```
Vue.use(require('@websanova/vue-auth'), {
  auth: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/auth/bearer.js'),
  http: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/http/axios.1.x.js'),
  router: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/router/vue-router.2.x.js'),
  loginData: {redirect: ''}
  rolesVar: 'role',
  ...
})
```

And I set my route like this :

```
path: '/admin',
name: 'admin.dashboard',
component: AdminDashboard,
meta: {
  auth: {roles: 2, redirect: {name: 'login'}, forbiddenRedirect: '/403'}
},
```

I hope this will help :)